# Is there a Python library for Oracle SQL?

Tags: python, sql, oracle

I've been looking across the internet to find some sort of library that will connect an Oracle database to a Python script, but so far I have been unsuccessful. If anyone has found a great library for Oracle, preferably first party, then please give me documentation. I'm working on a project now that particularly needs this integration. I've already seen lots of documentation for MySQL, which is maintained by Oracle, but that's about it.

Comment: Could you share your codes and errors, please?

Comment: [Documentation](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and [github](https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle provides the python library `cx_Oracle`. Like everything else produced by Oracle, the documentation leaves some to be desired and the drivers are an absolute pain in the ass, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

The library is cx_Oracle. It conforms to the [Python DB API 2.0](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249) specification with a number of additions and a couple of exclusions. The cx_Oracle creator is [Anthony Tuininga](https://github.com/anthony-tuininga). Since [2017](https://blogs.oracle.com/developers/oracle-database-python-driver-now-on-github) the cx_Oracle is manteined by Oracle and Anthony Tuininga joined to Oracle and making maintaining the driver his full time job.

The lib have a good [documentation](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) and are frequently updated. There are a bunch of [samples](https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/tree/master/samples) on cx_Oracle [github](https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle).